# Malloc in a loop causing memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

Can anybody help me with this simple piece of code it seems to be causing memory leaks but I don't know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* get_point()
{
    int* point = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    point[0] = 5;
    point[1] = 8;

    return point;
}

int main(void)
{
    int* point;
    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) 
    {
        point = get_point();
    }

    free(point);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that I'm not freeing point within the loop but aren't I just reassigning it a new block of memory? How do I get rid of the old memory from the last pass through the loop?

Can anybody suggest a solution to this when you call malloc indirectly through a loop? I know there may be a better way to fix this code to do the same thing but it would be nice to correct this extract so I can see what is causing the problem?

Comment: Apologies for calling my pointer "point", probably a better name would suit. I'm using point in terms of (x,y) on the 2D plane.

Answer (score 4):

Each iteration of the loop incurs a new allocation onto the heap. However you only free this allocated memory once, the final allocation. To ensure that the code does not leak you need to put the free inside of the loop:

Like so:

```
int main(void)
{
    int* point;
    int i;

    for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) 
    {
        point = get_point();
        free(point); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternative to this approach would be to allocate once outside of the function, and the loop, then pass that allocated data into the function.

Comment: Or you could make `point` `static` in `get_point()`.

Comment: When I free point do I not have to call int* point again because I freed it?

Comment: @alan4cult What do you mean "call int* point again"? If you're talking about the `int* point;` line at the beginning of the function, then no, you don't need that line again after you call `free()`. That bit doesn't have anything to do with allocating/freeing memory.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I wasn't sure. I thought that free(point) deallocates the memory pointed to and also deletes "point" from the stack as if it had never been declared.

Comment: @alan4cult nope, don't worry about "deleting from the stack", the stack takes care of itself. `free` simply deletes the data pointed to by the pointer, ie the data in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

you allocated 100 times, but only free once. For sure it has memory leak.

You need free all the dynamic memory with loop.

Answer (score 1):

> aren't I just reassigning it a new block of memory?

No. Every time you call `malloc()`, you assign a new memory block to `point`, and the previous one is lost.

Normally, to reassign memory to an existing pointer, you use `realloc()`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_point(int **p)
{
    *p = realloc(2*sizeof *p);
    if (*p)
    {
      (*p)[0] = 5;
      (*p)[1] = 8;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int *point = NULL;
    int i;

    for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) 
    {
        get_point(&point);
    }

    free(point);
    return 0;
}
```

But this code has little sense, as `realloc()` always calls for the same amount of memory. Given your example, you would go with something simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *get_point(void)
{
   int *p;
   p = malloc (2 * sizeof *p);
   if (p)
   {
     p[0] = 5;
     p[1] = 8;
   }
   return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *point = NULL;
    int i;

    for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) 
    {
        point = get_point(point);
        if (point)
        {
          /* do stuff with point */
          free (point);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop each time `malloc()` is called it looks for a free space in the memory and allocate the size passed as argument which means that each time it's called the pointer `point` is pointing to a new space in the memory and the previous space is lost but the memory in that space still reserved which leads to memory leaks.

To solve this you will have to call the [free()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) function to free the memory space before pointing to a new one:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) 
{
    point = get_point();
    free(point);
}
```

*Notice that the `free` function does not change the value of `point` itself, hence it still points to the same (now invalid) location.*

Comment: So when I call free(point) how come I don't have to redeclare point i.e. call int* point again. How does the compiler know point is still of type pointer to int if I have freed it?

Comment: @alan4cult When you call free you only free the memory space pointed to by `point` but the pointer `point` still exist. check this reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/

Comment: Thank you I think I understand. So the actual pointer (int *point) doesn't get "deleted" until it goes out of scope but the memory it points to can be freed.